# {:g} format in python flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, format, flask-sqlalchemy

I've read up on the g formatter, and it looks like exactly what I want, 
I have a SQL Alchemy Numeric which contains a value, may be 1, or 1.1

I'm trying to display it just exactly like that, only showing the decimals when it makes sense, etc.

I'm using the following in jinja2 template

```
    <div class="item">{{ '{:,g}'.format(item.item_number)  }}</div<
```

I always get a value like 1.000000000 in the template...

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Hm, this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, I had to convert it to a python float before it would work.
so something like

```
'{:,g}'.format(item.item_number | float)
```

fixed the issue.  I'd like to understand sql alchemy types, because they don't seem to relate to python types... don't quite get it.